# generate a clock in matlab with upgradation in value of C

Tags: matlab, simulink, clock

i want to generate a square clock using level 2-s function. i tried this.

```
function pll2( block)
%UNTITLED13 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
setup(block);

function setup(block)

% Register number of ports
block.NumInputPorts  = 1;
block.NumOutputPorts = 1;

block.InputPort(1).Dimensions        = 1;
block.InputPort(1).DatatypeID  = 0;  % boolean
block.InputPort(1).Complexity  = 'Real';
block.InputPort(1).DirectFeedthrough = true;


% Override output port properties

block.OutputPort(1).Dimensions  = 1;
block.OutputPort(1).DatatypeID  = 0; %double
block.OutputPort(1).Complexity  = 'Real';


  block.NumDialogPrms     = 1;
  block.DialogPrmsTunable = {'Tunable'};

 Ts = 1;

block.SampleTimes = [Ts 0];

% Specify the block simStateCompliance. The allowed values are:
%    'UnknownSimState', < The default setting; warn and assume DefaultSimState
%    'DefaultSimState', < Same sim state as a built-in block
%    'HasNoSimState',   < No sim state
%    'CustomSimState',  < Has GetSimState and SetSimState methods
%    'DisallowSimState' < Error out when saving or restoring the model sim state
block.SimStateCompliance = 'DefaultSimState';





block.RegBlockMethod('PostPropagationSetup',    @DoPostPropSetup);
%block.RegBlockMethod('InitializeConditions', @InitializeConditions);
%block.RegBlockMethod('Start', @Start);
block.RegBlockMethod('Outputs', @Outputs);     % Required
block.RegBlockMethod('Update', @Update);
%block.RegBlockMethod('Derivatives', @Derivatives);
block.RegBlockMethod('Terminate', @Terminate); % Required
%block.RegBlockMethod('SetInputPortSamplingMode', @SetInpPortFrameData);
%end setup


function DoPostPropSetup(block)
block.NumDworks = 1;

  block.Dwork(1).Name            = 'c';
  block.Dwork(1).Dimensions      = 1;
  block.Dwork(1).DatatypeID      = 0;%double     
  block.Dwork(1).Complexity      = 'Real'; % real
  block.Dwork(1).UsedAsDiscState = true;





function Outputs(block)




%block.Dwork(1).Data = counter;
t = block.CurrentTime;
l = 0.8*exp(-9);
%c = 220*exp(-15) + block.InputPort(1).Data*3*exp(-15);


f = 1/(2*pi*sqrt(l*(block.Dwork(1).Data)));

block.OutputPort(1).data = square(2*pi*f*t);


function Update(block)


c = block.Dwork(1).Data; 

c = 220*exp(-15) + block.InputPort(1).Data*3*exp(-15); %%  block.InputPort(1).data is a value which is updated         by another block, it is an integer value.

block.Dwork(1).Data = c;

 %counter = block.Dwork(1).Data;




%%
%% Terminate:
%%   Functionality    : Called at the end of simulation for cleanup
%%   Required         : Yes
%%   C-MEX counterpart: mdlTerminate
%%
function Terminate(block)


%end SetInpPortFrameData


%end Terminate
```

but the problem is this square clock does not work as i wanted it to, 
so is there any other way to generate a clock where u can **update** the value of capacitor C as needed as shown in the code by block.InputPort(1).Data. this block has been simulated in simulink.

Comment: In your code `u` is updating `c`.  You need to tell us what you are expecting/wanting and how that compares to what this is doing.

Comment: well i am expecting a square wave only. which this code is giving me. but i want to know is there any other way to get a square wave, in which i can update the value of C as i have done in this code.

Comment: There are so many different ways to do it that it's impossible to definitively answer your question.  It can very easily be done without using an S-Function.  You could also not use the `square` function, and just compare the value of sin(...) to 0 (i.e. is it positive or negative) to determine the output signal value.

Comment: you mean by using workspace in matlab

Comment: No.  Nothing to do with MATLAB.  Your code can be implemented in Simulink using blocks other than an S-Function.

Comment: like how? can you give me any example?

Comment: Can you please give me any example  Phil Goddard ?